# I am using for android SDK target version is 22 for READ_CONTACTS

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, sdk, android-permissions

I am used for the permission for ***read a contact*** for assign a permission in manifest. my question is that I am not go to the  increase the  sdk version to 23 to show a permission dialog (given by default by android)to the user and take a permission and go through it.in  the android sdk version 22.

- minSdkVersion = 16
  targetSdkVersion = 22
  compileSdkVersion = 27

  ```
  I am using this code right now.

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
              if (checkPermission()) {
                  Log.e("permission", "Permission already granted.");
              } else {
                  requestPermission();
              }
          }

  private boolean checkPermission() {
          int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(fragmentContext, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
          if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              return true;
          } else {

              return false;
          }
      }

      private void requestPermission() {
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) fragmentContext, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
      }


   @Override
      public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
          switch (requestCode) {
              case REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS:
                  if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                      Toast.makeText(fragmentContext,
                              "Permission accepted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  } else {
                      Toast.makeText(fragmentContext,
                              "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  }
                  break;
          }
      }
  ```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I am using to make a allow the check permission for target SDK Version 22

Comment: You want to show a permission accept/reject dialog for android SDK < 22?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On API 22 and below permissions are already granted if specified in
>   the manifest.

For API 23+ ContextCompat#checkSelfPermission could be of use. It "degrades" gracefully on earlier APIs and will tell you the permission is granted if it appears in the manifest. On API 23 and above it will actually check if it's granted.

Comment: please explain  in brief